# Rails : Caching a service call's result in case of multiple web servers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I'm fetching a reasonably large object during a service call. I need this data(for validation purposes) across multiple postbacks in a UI wizard flow.

I'm considering session storage(cookie store) to do this. But to lower the space occupied and simplify the complexity, I'm have to convert this data into a minimal object with the most important attributes.

I need this solution to work across multiple hosted web servers with a load balancer. I read through different cache stores in rails and found that I could only go for a memcached store for this scenario(multiple web servers).

What would be a good way to do this? Should I go for a memcached cache just for this?

Answer (score 0):

memcached is a good choice. Or alternatively, you can configure to save your session data into database, and save your "reasonably large object" in session. of course there would be some performance affects. but it's much simpler.